# NUCLEO-H723ZG HAL LWIP won't ping

Tags: stm32, ethernet, nucleo, mpu, lwip

I am having issues creating the simplest setup with this board. LWIP initializes, I can see my static IP address in the debugger. I can detect if cable is plugged-in/unplugged. MPU is configured and I am not getting "Hard Fault", but that's pretty much it. What am I doing wrong here?

here's my config:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Configuration look correct. Especially ICMP is enabled. As a debugging step you can try adding breakpoint to Ethernet interrupt handlers to see that they triggers. Another investigation method could be try communicate in reverse way to check that TCP/IP stack and link layer works. Instead of pinging device externaly try to write short code that send UDP packet from device and try to sniff it. When writing UDP (or other) code remember to check all return values from functions, they can bring you intereseting information.

Comment: Thanks however after doing some more research I decided its not worth the effort to stick with this buggy chip. There's literally mass of articles on the web describing how to workaround bugs on this mcu. I have decided to try other eth enabled mcu instead.

Comment: I do not think it is hardware issue. I think it is software issue and it is possible to debug it. Note that HW of ethernet controller is not designed by ST, but ST licenced design from synopsys for their MCU. Generaly this peripheral work and you were most probably facing software issue. Ethernet drivers and networking stack are complicated piece of software. If you have not enough experience to debug this issue, going more tweeked platform is also way. What MCU did you select? I have exprience with Renesas RA6M4 MCU and EK-RA6M4 devkit. Ethernet, FreeRTOS and lwip combination work well there.

Comment: @Misaz yes you are right it is a software issue. HAL for this chip is not quite there yet. I selected NUCLEO-F207ZG because theres some working HAL + lwip examples for it on the web. No I don't think I have enough experience to debug problems with ethernet stack. I am quite ok with IT side of things but basic stuff like this I would just expect to work with HAL out of the box.